# Laravel Json Response getKey does not exist in testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I've got a Laravel 8 test that mocks one of my notifications, I'm creating my user in my database in my setup function and then am proceeding to mock one of my notifications, bizarely even after following the docs, I still get the following error:

> Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::getKey does not exist.

I wonder what I'm missing?

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;

use App\Notifications\DomainExpiry;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Tests\TestCase;

class NotificationsTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected $user;

    /**
    * Setup function
    *
    * @return void
    */
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $email = 'hello@example.com';
        $password = Hash::make('password');

        $user = User::factory()->raw([
          'email' => $email,
          'password' => $password,
          'password_confirmation' => $password
        ]);

        $this->user = $user;

        $responseCreate = $this->withHeaders([
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ])->post('/api/account/create', $user);
    }

    /**
     * User can get a list of notifications
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_user_can_get_a_list_of_notifications()
    {

        $token = $this->loginUsingCredentials([
          'email' => $this->user['email'],
          'password' => $this->user['password']
        ]);

        $user = $this->withHeaders([
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
          'Authorization' => "Bearer $token"
        ])->get('/api/auth/user', $this->user);

        Notification::fake();
        Notification::assertNothingSent();

        Notification::assertSentTo(
            [$user], DomainExpiry::class
        );

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to call `fake()` before the `api` call. The app is bootstrapped on call, there it will use notifications so it needs to be faked before, else it will call notifications with bad config settings.

So i assume the error is a smokescreen for that problem.

```
Notification::fake();

$user = $this->withHeaders([
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => "Bearer $token"
])->get('/api/auth/user', $this->user);

Notification::assertNothingSent();
```

Calling `assertNothingSent()` and `assertSentTo()` in same test does not make sense, but i guess the first problem is the `getKey()` error.

Comment: I've tried moving `Notification::fake()`, there's no difference in the error I get back, I get the same error: `Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::getKey does not exist`

Comment: You also call the api in the setup, that can also cause trouble.

Comment: Yes, because I need to create multiple tests, and so the set up function makes sense to create my users without duping that code in each test. What would your suggestion be to resolve the `getKey` issue?

Comment: The way laravell bootstrap the application in tests, you should only call the api once during each test. If you need an user created use factories